# I have identical getter/setter code used for multiple virtual attributes - can I refactor with eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, model, refactoring, virtual-attribute

I have written customised getter and setter methods for virtual attributes to convert decimals into integers for storage in a database.  This is one of three virtual attributes (annual_fee_dollars) that get/sets from a real attributes (annual_fee) in the database:

```
def annual_fee_dollars
  @annual_fee_dollars || int_to_dec(annual_fee)
end

def annual_fee_dollars=(string)
  @annual_fee_dollars = string
  self.annual_fee = dec_to_int(string)
end
```

Instead of repeating all this code three times, does it make sense to / is it safe to / is it the 'Rails Way' to refactor the code like this:

```
def self.decimal_get_and_set(variable, suffix)
  eval (
    "def #{variable + suffix}
      @#{variable + suffix} || int_to_dec(self.#{variable})
    end
    def #{variable+suffix}=(string)
      @#{variable+suffix} = string
      self.#{variable} = dec_to_int(string)
    end")
end
self.decimal_get_and_set "annual_fee", "_dollars"
self.decimal_get_and_set "interest_purchase", "_percent"
self.decimal_get_and_set "interest_cash", "_percent"
```

Or is there a much cleaner way to build this type of functionality?

Apologies if this is a 'subjective question'.  In part, all refactoring questions have some  subjectivity to them, but I think this question still has a place on SO.  Happy to be corrected on this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is fine, but I wouldn't suggest using `eval`, mainly because there is already a more appropriate ruby metaprogramming way to do this.  Read up on the documentation for [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000497) and the object methods [`instance_variable_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001028) and [`instance_variable_set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001029).

Looks like what you want and you don't need to use `eval` yourself.  I would probably suggest something like the following, but you're right - all refactoring questions are somewhat subjective by their very nature.  Good luck!

```
{'annual_fee' => '_dollars', 'interest_purchase' => '_percent', 'interest_cash' => '_percent'}.each_pair do |variable, suffix|
  # Define getters
  define_method "#{variable+suffix}" do
    instance_variable_get("@#{variable+suffix}") || int_to_dec(send("#{variable}")
  end

  # Define setters
  define_method "#{variable+suffix}=" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not have a method which gets and sets a value given a property name, define 2 getters and setters for both the aliased methods to **curry** the defined method. I would do that rather than eval as I find that eval code can make stuff more confusing depending on how you use it. The code you showed `Brett` is in no way super complex, but for readability I feel this is heavy-handing the problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  This seems a lot cleaner - and easier to read - than the 'eval' solution.  I wasn't aware of the various class/module methods you've used (instance_variable_get, et al).  I'm still tempted to wrap your two 'define_methods' in a class method, then call it three times (once for each attribute) - rather than set up the 'each_pair' do loop.  I can't explain why except that it'll be clearer when editing in the future.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Dmitriy - I hadn't heard of the curry method.  Having looked into it, I'm not sure I have the Ruby smarts to implement it well.  Also, I'm running 1.8.7 - looks like curry wasn't introduced until 1.9.0?

Comment: The getter method is slightly wrong - it's either fetching instance variable or (if it is nil) fetching int_to_dec of the instance variable.  I've corrected it to fetch the underlying attribute using the send method